# Error when using async Next.js 13 page in Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I'm trying to use Storybook with an async page in Next.js 13, but I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve. Here's the structure of my code:
I am using some apis and other action that requires async I can use separate functions, but I want to test how will this work with storybook.

component

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default async function Page({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string };
}) {
  ... using some API or other task that require async.


  return (
    <div>
            hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

story book

```
import Page from "./page";
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";

const meta: Meta<typeof Confirmed> = {
    title: "Pages",
    component: Page,
}

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof Confirmed>;

export const SomePage: Story  = {
    args: {
        searchParams: {
         ...some value
        }
    }
}
```

error i am getting

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-essentials_dist_actions_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybo-83935b.iframe.bundle.js:40430:9)
    at reconcileChildFibers (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-essentials_dist_actions_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybo-83935b.iframe.bundle.js:41371:7)
    at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-essentials_dist_actions_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybo-83935b.iframe.bundle.js:44705:28)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-essentials_dist_actions_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybo-83935b.iframe.bundle.js:45695:5)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-essentials_dist_actions_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybo-83935b.iframe.bundle.js:47125:16)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-essentials_dist_actions_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybo-83935b.iframe.bundle.js:52964:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-essentials_dist_actions_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybo-83935b.iframe.bundle.js:52095:12)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-essentials_dist_actions_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybo-83935b.iframe.bundle.js:52004:5)
    at renderRootSync (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-essentials_dist_actions_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybo-83935b.iframe.bundle.js:51972:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-essentials_dist_actions_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybo-83935b.iframe.bundle.js:51388:20)
```